# How to jump to a specific portion on another PHP page while also passing variables by Get method?

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink, get, anchor

My code is something like this
Page A.php: has `<a href ="B.php#comment?id=4&Pagenumber=5">Click</a>`

Page B.php: has `<a name="comment">Comment</a>` tag and also need variable 'Id' and 'Pagenumber'

It doesn't work... help me please.

Comment: @Phelios you should add it as an answer instead +1

Comment: Thanks Phelios.I have tried to put # after the Get variables, but still error.

Comment: what error are you getting. and how are you trying to retrieve the value

Answer (score 3):

put the `#` after the Get variables. `<a href ="B.php?id=4&Pagenumber=5#comment">Click</a>`

Comment: <a href ="B.php?id=4&Pagenumber=5#comment">Click</a>    OK it's work (after check many things) Thanks Phelios :)